# Scrolling on question pages sluggish on iPhone 4S

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

After an update of the iOS app a couple days ago (sorry, I don't remember exactly when), scrolling through question pages (*i.e.*, where a question and its answers are displayed) became really sluggish on my iPhone 4S. On the other hand, scrolling through the feed or through any particular site is fine.

Comment: I'm not having this problem on my 4S. Which version of the app are you using fk, and is there any particular questions that are especially bad?

Comment: I am using version 1.2.2.189, which I suppose is the latest since I am not prompted to install a new one, but the problem appeared with a previous update. If there is a way to download previous versions, I can pinpoint the exact version where the problem appeared. All questions are the same, regardless of length or number of answers. I also forgot to mention that I am still on iOS 7.

Comment: I'm on the same app version, but iOS8 - so maybe it's iOS7 thing? I doubt there's many users on 7.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in 1.2.2.199.  It was actually pegging the CPU on my MacBook when scrolling in the iPad Air simulator.  We added a draft indicator icon (which wasn't even onscreen) and every time you scrolled it was recalculating the height of the title area (an incredibly expensive operation).  Instead I'm just checking whether or not the header is onscreen and if it is reading its current height.