# Lag when viewing questions

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, ios-app

Basically, the title says all. The SE iOS app works fine and smooth, but when I open a question (any question) and view it, it becomes very lag. The FPS drops significantly. When I click into a question, the title loads and the question loads, but when I swipe up to scroll down, it moved frame by frame slowly instead of a smooth run. It doesn't go away as long as I am in the question and answer page. Happens on the development build. AppStore version works fine.

How can this be fixed? What is causing this?

I am using an iPhone 5, iOS7, app version SEß 1.2.2.198

Comment: Any question? If not, maybe only questions with lots of answers? We need more information.

Comment: Any question. All questions lags the app.

Comment: Bad WiFi connection?

Comment: @PythonMaster I am talking about frame rate dropping, not the question not loading. It acts like there is no memory or space left for it to function.

Comment: I understand now

Comment: Are you seeing this in the App Store version?  Is it only on question views or does it start when the question appears and remain when the question disappears?  Is it laggy when just a single post body or just comments are on the screen?  Is it laggy initially but then speeds up after a short time?

Comment: Someone else on iOS7 reported a similar thing [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248386/233816). (CC @Brian)

Comment: @Chris Thanks.  I'll be digging up my 4S tonight to try this out.

Comment: @BrianNickel alright ill edit my question and add more info. Basically when I click into a question, the title loads and the question loads, but when I swipe up to scroll down, it moved frame by frame slowly instead of a smooth run. It doesn't go away as long as I am in the question and answer page. Happens on the development build. AppStore version works fine.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate but I just pushed out a fix for this in the beta channel.